# Magento 2.3.3 - "Be the first to write a review" link is stopped clicking after upgrades to magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

**Magento 2.3.3:-** 
"**Be the first to write a review**" and "**Add your Review**" link on the product detail page is stopped clicking after upgrades to Magento 2.3.3. There is no error in the console. Anybody have solution for it?

Comment: What do you mean by stopped clicking? Does the link not work any more? Can you inspect it and maybe share the code?